# How do I add a UITableView to a parent that contains other objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5

This is essentially the layout I want:

[image]

The UITableView at the bottom should accomodate comments to a specific post, adding a row for each comment.

The UITableView at the bottom is wired to `commentTable`; all other elements are wired accordingly as well.

When I build and run, no errors, but I only see one empty table cell below the post.

I know there's something missing in loading/passing data to my table, but I wonder if someone can give me a direction on how to make this work.

**DetailViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView  *postThumbView;
    IBOutlet UILabel      *postTextLabel;
    IBOutlet UIImageView  *postAuthorPictureView;
    IBOutlet UILabel      *postAuthorNameLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel      *postTimestampLabel;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    IBOutlet UITableView  *commentTable;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@end
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

- (void)configureView;

@end

@implementation DetailViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.detailItem) {
        NSDictionary *post           = self.detailItem;
        NSString     *postText       = [post objectForKey:@"post_text"];
        ...

        postTextLabel.text  = postText;
        ...
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *post           = self.detailItem;
    NSDictionary *commentThread  = [post objectForKey:@"comment"];

    return commentThread.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"commentCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *post           = self.detailItem;
    NSDictionary *commentThread  = [post objectForKey:@"comment"];

    NSString     *commentText       = [commentThread objectForKey:@"comment_text"];
    NSString     *commentAuthorName = [commentThread objectForKey:@"comment_author_name"];

    cell.textLabel.text = commentText;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", commentAuthorName];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you set/wired the delegate for the tableview? Are your delegate methods being called (eg, have you set breakpoints in the datasource methods)?

Comment: @isaac sorry for my ignorance, where should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your view controller as the delegate and data source for the table view

change this line in your `.h` file

`@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`

Then in your `viewDidLoad`

```
commentTable.dataSource = self;
commentTableView.delegate = self;
[commentTableView reloadData];
[self configureView];
```

You can also look in the story board, and connect the outlets n the same way you connected `commentTable` to your `UITableView`, but by dragging in the opposite direction and selecting data source and delegate

Comment: my JSON which contains posts and comments is being passed as `detailItem` -- so should it be `commentTable.dataSource = self.detailItem;` instead?

Comment: ah no, a bit of confusion there, when you say `commentTable.dataSource = self`, what you are in fact saying is that the view controller is implementing the `UITableViewDatasource` protocol, and that the table view should look at this class, and run the methods declared by this protocol (such as `cellForRowAtIndexPath`). You then tell the table view what to display in each row in this method, as you have done. Hence the change in your .h file, which is declaring your class as implementing the protocols declared

Comment: No worries, once you know, you know!

Comment: There should be no need to call reloadData. Also you stole my answer.

Comment: The call to reloaddata is there in case someone wanted to set the delegate and datasource later on, as it is it will cause no problem. Also, sadly, no, I did not steal your answer, there is more than one person who understands how to set a delegate on a table view. I assume you were also the one who downvoted my answer, very petty.

Comment: @P-double You posted the same answer shortly after (set the delegate). Either you didn't bother to read the existing answer, or you did read it and posted the exact same thing. Either way is bad SO etiquette.

Comment: @P-double And no, I'm not the only one in the world who knows how to use a tableview. I am however, the first one who took ten minutes to consider and correctly answer the question. Hence, on a platform that awards points for doing precisely what I did, I do indeed find it slightly irksome.

Comment: I answered the question at the same time as you! Do you think I'm just trolling around trying to steal peoples points? You also posted the wrong answer and have just edited it to the correct answer. I imagine if your answer was correct first time you may have got the points.

Comment: it's also pretty bad SO etiquette to downvote perfectly good answers because yours didn't get picked

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18239/discussion-between-p-double-and-isaac)

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the table view delegate method's you've written aren't being called. The first thing you should do is set breakpoints inside these methods, run your app, and see if they are being called.

If they're not being called, you may have failed to set your delegate. In this case, it appears that you are not using a discrete UITableViewController, rather you are attempting to have your DetailViewController supply the necessary information for the tableView to work as expected.

First, you need to conform your DetailViewController to the UITableViewDelegate protocol:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Second, you need to actually set the delegate @property of your UITableView. You can do this in interface builder (select the tableview, right click, drag it's delegate property to connect to your DetailViewController, which may or may not be File's Owner). If you'd rather do it in code, you just need to call (early in the VC's life, in viewDidLoad, for example):

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.datasource = self;
```

So... assuming your delegate is all wired up properly, you should then go back and test those breakpoints to see if the table view's methods are being called. If they are being called, the next step would be to evaluate the variables when the breakpoints are called, examine for example if the numbers being return in numberOfRowsInSection and the values in cellForRowAtIndexPath match what you anticipate.

Comment: do these lines go into the `h` or `m` DetailViewController file?

Comment: the first line goes in the .h, the second would be in the .m